# using a web service to relay calls to & from another web service in c#

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I have a 3rd party application that requires windows authentication to use its web services. I also have another 3rd party application that needs to consume these web services, however it is only capable of basic authentication when calling web services.

I have to create a web service that will act as the middleman that will relay the requests and responses between the two. Is there a better/easier way to do this than reading and reconstructing the soap messages on each call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this new "proxy" application will only be doing this one job, then I'd maybe use a windows service and HttpListener. Here's some code to get you started:

```
static class WebServer {
    private static readonly HttpListener Listener = new HttpListener { Prefixes = { "http://*/" } };
    private static bool _keepGoing = true;
    private static Task _mainLoop;

    public static void StartWebServer() {
        if (_mainLoop != null && !_mainLoop.IsCompleted) return;
        _mainLoop = MainLoop();
    }

    public static void StopWebServer() {
        _keepGoing = false;
        lock (Listener) {
            //Use a lock so we don't kill a request that's currently being processed
            Listener.Stop();
        }
        try {
            _mainLoop.Wait();
        } catch { /* je ne care pas */ }
    }

    private static async Task MainLoop() {
        Listener.Start();
        while (_keepGoing) {
            try {
                var context = await Listener.GetContextAsync();
                lock (Listener) {
                    if (_keepGoing) ProcessRequest(context);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e is HttpListenerException) return; //this gets thrown when the listener is stopped
                //handle bad error here
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) {
        string inputData;
        using (var body = context.Request.InputStream) {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(body, context.Request.ContentEncoding)) {
                inputData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        //inputData now has the raw data that was sent
        //if you need to see headers, they'll be in context.Request.Headers

        //now you can make the outbound request with authentication here

        //send result back to caller using context.Response
    }
}
```

The other option is you use ASP.NET Web API and IIS, but that's a lot of overhead. If you already have IIS running on the server you want this on, then that's an option. If not, I'd go the HttpListener route.